# Where are the abandoned carts saved?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, abandoned-cart

I am looking for a table in the database where the Abandoned Carts are saved, but I cannot find the correct place. Where are the Abandoned Carts saved in the database? Or are they saved in a different matter (for example by combining data)?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is available on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60888/get-all-abandoned-carts-in-magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific table that holds this data, this is the default SQL query which Magento will use to find abandoned carts.

```
SELECT
  `main_table`.*,
  (main_table.base_subtotal_with_discount * main_table.base_to_global_rate) AS `subtotal`,
  `cust_email`.`email`,
  `cust_fname`.`value`                                                      AS `firstname`,
  `cust_lname`.`value`                                                      AS `lastname`,
  CONCAT_WS(' ', cust_fname.value, cust_lname.value)                        AS `customer_name`
FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table`
  INNER JOIN `customer_entity` AS `cust_email` ON cust_email.entity_id = main_table.customer_id
  INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `cust_fname`
    ON cust_fname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND cust_fname.attribute_id = 5
  INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `cust_lname`
    ON cust_lname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND cust_lname.attribute_id = 7
WHERE (items_count != '0') AND (main_table.is_active = '1');
```

In case you weren't aware, you can find this data by going into the admin panel under Reports > Shopping Bag > Abandoned Shopping Bags.

Comment: I have indeed seen the list of abandoned shopping carts. In the meantime, I also found out, as you said, that the sales_flat_quote table holds the data for the abandoned cart. The only thing I am wondering now, what makes the abandoned cart 'abandoned'? As I am looking at your SQL query, I am guessing they are just looking if the user is currently online? Because, if I want to fire my own method, while a cart is considered abandoned, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
    $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport(array());
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($collection->getData());// will print all abandoned carts.
```